# Postgresql UPSERT using ON CONFLICT Error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to use UPSERT in postgresql. Below is my SQL string.

```
INSERT INTO dashboard.tblpurchaseordermaster (po_number,"po_created_TS", 
             vendor_code,"Refreshed_Datetime", 
             "Is_PO_Closed","PO_Closed_Date","TenderID","POVendorTender")
SELECT po_number,CAST("po_created_TS" AS date),vendor_code,current_timestamp,
      "Is_PO_Closed","PO_Closed_Date",
      "TenderID", 
      CONCAT(po_number,vendor_code,CAST("TenderID" AS varchar)) AS "POVendorTender"
      FROM pomaster_temp
ON CONFLICT ("POVendorTender") WHERE ("POVendorTender" NOTNULL)
DO UPDATE SET "po_created_TS" = EXCLUDED."po_created_TS",
              "Is_PO_Closed"=EXCLUDED."Is_PO_Closed",
              "PO_Closed_Date"=EXCLUDED."PO_Closed_Date";
```

I am getting an error as

```
21000-ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second timeON CONFLICT DO UPDATE 
command cannot affect row a second time--Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the 
same command have duplicate constrained values.-
```

Not able to figure out where I am missing?

P.S: `POVendorTender` is an Index key and being generated as combination of `po_number`, `vendor_code` and `TenderID`.

Comment: The error is telling you, the same row is being inserted into more then once. Run the select query by itself and I'm betting you will see duplicate rows.

Comment: Yes this is possible. However ON CONFLICT is meant to take care of the same, isn't it?

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT ON` to remove the duplicates that cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

[ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT):

> INSERT with an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause is a “deterministic” statement. This means that the command will not be allowed to affect any single existing row more than once; a cardinality violation error will be raised when this situation arises. Rows proposed for insertion should not duplicate each other in terms of attributes constrained by an arbiter index or constraint.

When the rows are INSERTed in a single statement, then the above applies.